# How Flex components can be used with Away3D?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, away3d

Is it possible to have Flex component in Away3D environment?
For example, there is 3D plane and there is interactive Flex component on that plane.

Comment: Have you tried anything other than asking this question? where's the code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can view a good tutorial here on a Flex Component with Away3D (this is better then me giving a brief explanation): http://www.flashmagazine.com/tutorials/detail/using_away3d_with_flex/

Comment: It's good tutorial, but it explains how to use Away3D in Flex. And I need to put Flex components in 3D.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem just now and solve it , so like to place here my solution :

Quick way to do it is create SpriteVisualElement , draw graphics with hole for Stage3D content and set it as 'mask' of Application . If You will mask deeper clips , dont forget to disable application background or set backgroundAlpha to 0 .